# Displaying posts of a category wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a wordpress theme from scratch. I have completed the design and am stuck at the listing of posts.

I am currently using:

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
```

It does display all the posts.

How can i display the posts in a category which is clicked?

I have no clue about how to achieve this. I tried to get the category name from URL and the pass it to the `get_posts()`. But i dont think this will be efficient because using different URL rewrite the URL can be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write your code in archive.php wordpress understand is a category and automatically return related posts otherwise by code you need to pass category id.

Example:

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10,'cat'=>1 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: I know about this, but i need after clicking on the category link

Comment: maybe i don't understand, when you click link you need load post of category without change url right?

Comment: You are right. I had wrong imagination about wordpress